# tracking IE specific errors?

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging

as im developing our site i run into IE specific errors where you would get a warning in the status bar of IE stating "Done but with errors" with the warning icon. once you double click that you get

```
LINE:203
CHAR:2
ERROR: Object Required
CODE: 0
URL: www.some site.com/some page
```

do you have any tips on how i could possibly track down this sort of error? or is my only hope to go thru all dependent files and look for line 203 and try to track it that way?
thanks

Comment: If it's IE8, use the developer console to try to debug the error (It's actually quite decent)...

Comment: it's probably line 203 of the web page, assuming you have in-page javascript.  if so make sure you look at the source of the page on the client (i.e. view source),  not the source of the page on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "line 203" would not be in the PHP code (which the browser never sees), but in either the HTML page itself (possibly an embedded script), or in a linked JavaScript file. "Object Required" does sound more like a JavaScript error.

As ircmaxwell says, check to see if the error appears in IE8, and use the developer tools to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is more likely a javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

IE very seldom, if ever, properly reports where the error actually occured. You might as well treat that line number as completely random, and use the javascript debugger and/or IE developer tools, which give you the option of jumping directly to the source of the error, where it actually occured.